# I can vote for myself in the moderator election but not in the primaries

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, election

I am running for moderator in the [EL&U election](https://english.stackexchange.com/election).

I can vote for myself in the final stage of the election. I couldn't vote for myself in the primaries. Is this a feature or a bug?

[image: Voting for myself]

Comment: It's a feature.

Comment: Is your bug the fact that you can't in the primaries, or that you can in the election?

Comment: Can't speak for Matt but I consider it a bug that you can't vote for yourself in the primary.

Comment: Well, I suppose I see the inconsistency as a bug.

Comment: There's a fine line between a feature and a bug.

Comment: The ability to do this seemed intentional but I felt bad and picked myself as third choice

Comment: I know this is off-topic, but... of all the sites in the network, you had to pick EL&U to use Cyrillic in your display name?

Comment: How come I didn't get a notification that the election phase began? :<

Comment: @PopularDemand I could try to explain, but I'm not sure I really remember myself. Something to do with having Sir Elton John as a mod.

Comment: First of all, that's Sir Reginald Kenneth Dwight, Commander of the Most Excellent Order of the British Empire to you. Secondly, you're still lacking in the Greek department, unlike me. Thirdly and most importantly, Lauren and Aarthi started it. Fourthly, we also have one JSBձոգչ running.

Comment: @PopularDemand lol, I had that exact thought.

Comment: I don't even need to remember! [Chat can explain all!](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=1530977#1530977)

Answer (score 6):

It follows life.

Turning up for the primaries as a candidate is your self vote for yourself.

Then, just like in regular real-life elections (which may or may not be run by a junta (and which may or may not be on a day designed to have maximum voter turnout)), you can cast a ballot in your favour when it comes down to the final straw of elections.

Comment: I see. We don't do primaries in the UK, so I've not experienced that. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Swap out primaries for putting name on ballot and marking a box for voting for yourself and it'll work the same

Comment: In real life, at least in primaries I've participated in, parties nominate candidates onto the primary ballot, and then nominees have a vote just like anybody else and can vote for themselves in the primary election. Would be curious to see a counterexample.